# Sed, awk, grep or something else. Remove subdomains from list if parent domain present

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a list of domains:

```
test.example.com
example.com
example.test.com
test.test.com
test.com
test.example.example.org
example.example.org
```

I need to remove all subdomains if parent domain present.
Output will must be like this:

```
example.com
test.com
example.example.org
```

This is possible?

Comment: How about `co.uk` domains?

Comment: try to give your (failing) test showing that you already try somethiong and not asking "code for free".

Comment: I would turn for python to do things like this

Comment: Or `com.br`  This is a task that you do not get a simple answer to.

Comment: @anubhava: That's not a problem unless the list includes `co.uk`, which is unlikely.

Comment: @rici How do you what the OPs list contains or not contains, other than the example above?

Comment: @jotne: I'm applying common sense. But the example above doesn't include `co.uk` or `com.br`, and I don't see any reason why it would,, given the problem. If it did include one of those, what would be the problem with just removing the children, since that is what is requested?

Answer (score 3):

The following depends on `rev` which is not Posix standard but is readily available.

```
rev file.txt |
sort |
awk 'NR!=1&&substr($0,0,length(p))==p{next}{p=$0".";print}' |
rev
```

From `man rev`:

> The rev command is part of the util-linux package and is available from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/

You can implement reverse with `awk` (it doesn't have to be character by character; this one goes segment by segment):

```
awk -F. '{for (i=NF; i>1; --i) printf "%s.",$i;print $1}'
```

Using that, the above pipeline becomes a bit longer:

```
awk -F. '{for (i=NF; i>1; --i) printf "%s.",$i;print $1}' file.txt |
sort |
awk -F. 'NR!=1&&substr($0,0,length(p))==p{next}
         {p=$0".";for (i=NF; i>1; --i) printf "%s.",$i;print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/.*/²&³/;H
${g
:a
   s/\²\([^³]*³\)\(.*\).²[^³]*\1/²\1\2/
   ta
:b
   s/.²[^³]*\.\([^³]*³\)\(.*\)²\1/\2²\1/;tb
   s/[²³]//g;s/^\n//
   p
   }' YourFile
```

load all the file in buffer with delimiter, than change any string found as end substring on another line. finaly remove delimiter and print

Answer (score 0):

A solution with memory: firstly data is loaded into a hash and then lines are skipped if, when transformed, they are in the hash.

When running the script, note that the input file is passed twice as an argument

```
USAGE: remove_subdomains.awk myfile1 myfile1
```

and here comes the script `remove_subdomain.awk`

```
# remove_subdomain.awk
FNR == NR {
    memory[toupper($0)] = 42
    next
}

match($0, /^[^.]+\.(.+)$/, mdata) {
    if (toupper(mdata[1]) in memory)
        $0 = ""
}

$0
```